# Rotate line segment with Button

Tags: math, javafx, geometry, coordinates

I have a line which has points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2). I wanted to attach a Button to it, it should align with the line by rotating based on the line segment points. I need some help in calculating the rotation angle for the Button.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Math.atan2(dy, dx)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2-double-double-) to get the angle `theta` from the conversion of rectangular coordinates (x, y) to polar coordinates (r, theta). Later use it to convert it to degrees.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
}

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        double startX = 100;
        double endX = 250;
        double startY = 150;
        double endY = 250;

        Line line = new Line(startX, startY, endX, endY);
        Button button = new Button("Button");

        double rad  = Math.atan2(endY - startY, endX - startX);
        double degree = rad * 180/Math.PI;
        button.setRotate(degree);

        StackPane box = new StackPane(line, button);

        Scene scene = new Scene(box, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

**OutPut**

[image]

Comment: I used the same logic , but it is not coming.

Comment: now i got the solution, i was not taking the absolute differences of the points. But any ways thanks for you reply...

Comment: I have attached a MCVE, you can copy it and run it to see the output.